# Sending selected ids with one button with laravel checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

There are id values ​​as in the photo below and I want to send them into a function, but in the examples I have examined, they are not sent with a single button, so since it is in the foreach, the button is constantly produced. How can I send the selected id values ​​with a single button?

[ID's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVhXk.png)

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input id="tea-submit" type="submit1" class="btn btn-primary mt-35" name="submit1" value="Send">
</div>


    @foreach ($pks as $pk)
     <tr>
     <td class="text-center">
     <form action="{{route('admin.pks.calculate')}}" method="POST">
      @csrf
     <input type="checkbox" name="pk_id[]" value="{{$pk->id}}">
      </form>
      {{ $pk->id }}
     </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach

public function calculate(Request $request)
    {
        $pk_ids = $request->input('pk_id');
        dd($pk_ids);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean a single button ?

Comment: I want it to send all the selected id values ​​when I select it from the checkbox and press the submit button. @Lk77

Comment: But it can't work, there is a form for each checkbox, move the form out of the foreach then

Comment: If I move the form outside the foreach how do I get the id values? @Lk77

Comment: well when you submit the form. the form is still there, it's just that there is only one form, and the input are still in the foreach. I don't say move the form and all elements inside, but jut the <form></form> tag without touching the rest

Comment: can you give an example? @Lk77

Comment: please update the code above, so you can see if you change it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one form element and do the foreach to the inputs, like this:

```
<form action="{{route('admin.pks.calculate')}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @foreach($pks as $pk)
     <tr><td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pk_id[]" value="{{ $pk->id }}"> {{ $pk->id }}
     </td></tr>
   @endforeach
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yes it was that way, but I have another problem. There is a pagination structure and how can I get the previous selected boxes when I switch to another page? @RobsonSousa

Comment: First of all, in this kind of system you only can know the selected if you save it in the database before go to another page. So that said, you need to send the selected ids to your view. And in your view you can check if that id is in the selected array:
`<input type="checkbox" name="pk_id[]" value="{{ $pk->id }}" @if(in_array($pk->id, $selectedIds)) checked @endif>`